# hoh can I view angular website in localhost

Tags: angularjs

maybe a stupid question but I don't succedd to view angular website as local host.
this is the website i downloaded : https://github.com/kenyee/angularjs-cart

i see only the title ang get error in console :

```
"XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/--name--/Dropbox/angularjs-cart-master/angularjs-cart-master/ShoppingCart/partials/store.htm. Received an invalid response. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. "
```

thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

If the url says similar to file:///C:/Users/... its not running on localhost.. its just open as a file.

It needs to be ran from a 'server'..

If using Windows add the folder as a site on IIS, on Mac use something like MAMP..

Or open the folder in an IDE (Editor) that runs a server automatically for you.. such as Visual Studio or Brackets.

If you can let me know which your using I can add more info if you need it.

UPDATED: although it's true a raw angular page is client side and doesn't need to run from a server.. if it's pulling in other files from the local file system. (i.e. scripts / css / templates / partials) it needs to be running on a server as the browser doesn't have access to just pull in files from the file system unless they are served via server.. (for obvious security reasons)

Comment: sorry, i mean open the site by just clicking on the default.html file. I must have server?

Answer (score 0):

You should have no issues viewing an AngularJS website in localhost.
AngularJS is client side.

EDIT: I downloaded and checked all of the pages for you. It loads up nice on my side. Just remember since AngularJS is client side you don't need a server. Instead of running it on localhost (I assume XAMPP or something is what your using), just right click + open with a browser.

Remember to open the main html (default.html) first, and perhaps read some html/css/js docs before jumping strait into AngularJS!

Good luck!

Comment: thanks.. i opened it the way you said (right click + open with a browser) , my mistake. i can't see the site...

Answer (score 0):

```
    If You have Xampp installed on your system then put ShoppingCart folder in 
    xampp/htdocs folder`

   After This hit the url 
   [http://localhost/ShoppingCart/#]. 
   It will work as this application on my system.
```

Answer (score 0):

You definitely need a local server (WAMP on Windows or Lamp on Linux) to run Angular application as David Beech suggests. In my case I couldn't figure out why this simple Angular check form code from [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/U5yFT7inY6LyAaC6Uqjy?p=preview) wouldn't work properly on my computer (it didn't seem to lead the css code).

```html
<body ng-app="formExample">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <form novalidate class="css-form">
    Name: <input type="text" ng-model="user.name" required /><br />
    E-mail: <input type="email" ng-model="user.email" required /><br />
    Telephone: <input type="number" ng-model="user.number" required /><br />
    <input type="submit" ng-click="update(user)" value="Save" />
  </form>
</div>

<style type="text/css">
  .css-form input.ng-invalid.ng-touched {
    background-color: #FA787E;
  }

  .css-form input.ng-valid.ng-touched {
    background-color: #78FA89;
  }
</style>

<script>
  angular.module('formExample', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.master = {};

      $scope.update = function(user) {
        $scope.master = angular.copy(user);
      };

      $scope.reset = function() {
        $scope.user = angular.copy($scope.master);
      };

      $scope.reset();
    }]);
</script>
</body>
```

I did my search on google, found this great example of [Single Page Angular App](https://scotch.io/tutorials/single-page-apps-with-angularjs-routing-and-templating) where it says **you need** some local environment, otherwise Angular routing won't work. I fired my Wamp server, put the code to "www" directory, and lo and behold, the angular triggered css worked just fine.